# Cannot get historical comments to display in a view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a comments form to a blog post, and have historical comments displayed, too.  I created two partials.  I can see the comment form in the posts/show view, and I can leave comments, and the comments are added to the database, but those comments are 
**not displayed**.

How can I get these historical comments to be displayed?

Here are my relevant files/excerpts:

app/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: '/comments/comment', locals: { comments: @comments}  %> 

<%= render partial: '/comments/form', locals: { comment: @comment } %>
```

app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<% comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body + " " + comment.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@post, comment] do |f| %> 
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @topic = @post.topic
  @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.post = @post
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to [@topic, @post], notice: "Comment was saved successfully."
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error creating comment.  Please try again."
    render :new
  end 
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, if you're sure the comments are being created correctly (and associated with the right post), then there are two main possibilities:

1. There's something wrong with the way you're rendering the partial. The convention is to leave off the leading `/`, and I think it might lead to the wrong path (so `comments/comment`). That said, I think that would raise an error if it didn't find the file, not be silent.
2. There's some sort of styling or conditional logic hiding the partial. Is there a condition around it that might be false? Is anything `display: none` for any reason?

The @comments variable **could** be instantiating incorrectly, but it looks reasonable to me. You can test that out by just adding this line to the top of the show view, and seeing what is printed:

`<%= @comments %>`

If a bunch of comments are printed, then I'd take that line out, and see what happens when you add `<%= comments %>` just inside the partial. Narrow down the problem, til you see where it is -- because your above code looks good to me when I look it over.